# How to write SQL case statement with multiple conditions to search by user using group by?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to search within each individual user using a case statement that has multiple conditions before it ends up true.
What the statement needs to do is to search for each user to see if they came consecutively to the exclusion of other days.

```
select
    user_id,
    case
        when dates = 'Monday' and dates = 'Wednesday' then 'not_retained'
        when dates = 'Monday' and dates = 'Tuesday' and dates = 'Wednesday' then 'retained'
        else null
        end as retention_of_user
from
    retention_group
group by
    user_id,
    case
        when dates = 'Monday' and dates = 'Wednesday' then 'not_retained'
        when dates = 'Monday' and dates = 'Tuesday' and dates = 'Wednesday' then 'retained'
        else null
        end
```

When I use the query above, the case statement returns nulls

I have included a sample table of data.

```
retinetion_group

user_id dates

User1   Monday
User1   Tuesday
User1   Wednesday

User2   Monday
User2   Wednesday

User3   Tuesday
User3   Monday
User3   Wednesday
User3   Wednesday

User4   Tuesday
User4   Wednesday
```

Here are the results I would like to get.

```
Results
user_id retention_of_user

User1   retained
User2   not_retained
User3   retained
User4   NULL
```

Comment: I'm just lost.  You have `user_id` and `device_id` and multiple conditions in a `case` that will never evaluate to true.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I am sorry about the typo. I think my case logic is wrong. I was using IN operator but realised that it functioned like and OR. I wanted to write a case statement logic that looks at a user and sees if they came on Monday AND Tuesday AND Wednesday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you want:

```
select user_id,
       (case when countif(dates = 'Monday') > 0 and countif(dates = 'Wednesday')
             then 'not_retained'
             when countif(dates = 'Monday') > 0 and countif(dates = 'Tuesday') > 0 and countif(dates = 'Wednesday') > 0 
             then 'retained'
             else null
        end) as retention_of_user
from retention_group
group by user_id;
```

Answer (score 3):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.retention_group` AS (
  SELECT 'User1' user_id, 'Monday' dates UNION ALL
  SELECT 'User1', 'Tuesday' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'User1', 'Wednesday' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'User2', 'Monday' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'User2', 'Wednesday' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'User3', 'Tuesday' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'User3', 'Monday' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'User3', 'Wednesday' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'User3', 'Wednesday' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'User4', 'Tuesday' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'User4', 'Wednesday' 
)
SELECT user_id, 
  CASE 
    WHEN 'Monday' IN UNNEST(dates) AND 'Tuesday' IN UNNEST(dates) AND 'Wednesday' IN UNNEST(dates) THEN 'retained'
    WHEN 'Monday' IN UNNEST(dates) AND 'Wednesday' IN UNNEST(dates) THEN 'not_retained'
    ELSE NULL
  END retention_of_user
FROM (
  SELECT user_id, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT dates) dates  
  FROM `project.dataset.retention_group`
  GROUP BY user_id
)
```

with result

```
Row user_id retention_of_user    
1   User1   retained     
2   User2   not_retained     
3   User3   retained     
4   User4   null
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing something like this

```
select user_id,
       case
           when (select count(*) from retention_group x1 where x1.user_id = x._user_id and 
         x1.dates = 'Monday' ) >0
          and
             (select count(*) from retention_group x1 where x1.user_id = x._user_id and x1.dates = 'Tuesday' ) >0
            and
          (select count(*) from retention_group x1 where x1.user_id = x._user_id and x1.dates = 'Wednesday' ) >0
         then 'retained'

           when (select count(*) from retention_group x1 where x1.user_id = x._user_id and x1.dates = 'Monday' ) >0
           and
         (select count(*) from retention_group x1 where x1.user_id = x._user_id and x1.dates = 'Tuesday' ) =0
           and
          (select count(*) from retention_group x1 where x1.user_id = x._user_id and x1.dates = 'Wednesday' ) >0
           then 'not_retained'
           else NULL
       end as retaining
from 
    retention_group x
```